# Upload a file to Autodesk Forge - ESOCKETTIMEDOUT error

Tags: node.js, autodesk-data-management

I am new to **Autodesk-Forge API** and I am trying to use the sample `dmSample.js`, included in the `node.js` SDK.

The example works well for very small files (up to 500 Kb)

However, when I try to upload larger files, (even just 1 Mb), the execution stops after few seconds with the following error message :

```
Error: { Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\node.js dev\forge-api-nodejs-client node_mo dules\request\request.js:819:19)
     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:185:7)
     at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:629:10)
     at TLSSocket.g (events.js:292:16)
     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
     at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:338:8)
     at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14) code: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT', connect: false 
}
```

The file I am trying to upload is 30 Mb and is on my local post.

Any idea ?

Comment: from your description, it seems like a connection problem. Can you try from a different network? Maybe your firewall is blocking, on some other blocking.

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by increasing the value of the timeout of the request module.

Forge uses a wrapper that it is located in

> /src/ApiClient.js

Search for **this.timeout** and set it to something like.

```
this.timeout = 600000;
```